# How to bundle only actually used code with WebPack

Tags: webpack

With mobile devices in mind, I'd like to keep the amount of code that needs parsing on the client to a minimum.

Is it possible with WebPack to only bundle the subset of vendor code actually used by my SPA?

This would require WebPack to parse and understand my code so that it figures out what vendor functionality might get called at runtime.

spa.js

```
console.log(
  `Result is: ${add(1, 1)}`
);
```

vendor.js

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

// DO NOT BUNDLE
function subtract(a, b) { return a - b; }
```

Comment: if it is properly exported and imported, webpack does it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack does this by default from webpack 2 onwards. You can read more about the implementation in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)